# How to correct call API search request with debounce?

Tags: android, kotlin, search, android-jetpack-compose, debouncing

I tried to setup correct API call with debounce. Now I have function in ViewModel which call API search request with delay (debounce) and unique (latest) value, but as many as there are changes in the TextField in one time after debounce

This my code:

UI:

```
val searchedText by viewModel.searchText.collectAsState()

OutlinedTextField(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(15.dp),
                value = searchedText,
                onValueChange = { newText ->
                    viewModel.updateSearchedText(newText)
                    if (newText.isNotEmpty()) {
                        viewModel.getSearchedNotifications(5, 0)
                    } else {
                        viewModel.getAllNotifications(5, 0)
                    }
                },
```

ViewModel:

```
private val _searchText = MutableStateFlow("")
    val searchText: StateFlow<String> = _searchText

@OptIn(FlowPreview::class, ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    fun getSearchedNotifications(
        take: Int,
        skip: Int
    ) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _searchText
                .debounce(2000L)
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .collectLatest { searched ->
                    val response = notificationsRepository.getNotifications(
                        take,
                        skip,
                        searched
                    )
                    when (response) {
                        is Resource.Success -> {
                            _notifications.update {
                                response.data
                            }
                        }

                        is Resource.Error -> {

                        }

                        else -> {}
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

For example, I wrote in TextField "acc", delay 2 second and after that I had 3 API requests with same parametr acc. Expected that must be only one request with this parametr after user cancel entering and delay will overed.

Comment: For each letter "a", "c", "c" `onValueChange` is called which in turn calls `getSearchedNotifications`. Each time that function is called a new flow is created, debounced and collected. That's why it is called three times. Instead, only create and collect the flow once. But, since [flows shouldn't be used to store TextField values](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/effective-state-management-for-textfield-in-compose-d6e5b070fbe5) you should probably completely restructure that entire logic anyways.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Leviathan's comment, TextFields are very buggy with flows, so you should use State instead of StateFlow to hold your TextField's text.

And you are creating a new flow every time your function is called, which means you have multiple flows updating your `_notifications` State or Flow.

Instead, you can use your function to update a flow or flows that feed into a single flow that you create only once and make persistent using `shareIn` or `stateIn`. Something like this:

```
var searchText by mutableStateOf("")
    private set

private val notificationsTakeAndSkip = MutableSharedFlow<Pair<Int, Int>>(replay = 1)

@OptIn(FlowPreview::class, ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
val notifications = snapshotFlow { searchText }
    .debounce(2000L)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .combineTransform(notificationsTakeAndSkip.distinctUntilChanged()) { searched, (take, skip) ->
        val response = notificationsRepository.getNotifications(
            take,
            skip,
            searched
        )
        when (response) {
            is Resource.Success -> emit(response.data)
            is Resource.Error -> { }
            else -> { }
        }
    }
    .shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000L), replay = 1) 

fun setSearchedNotificationsParameters(take: Int, skip: Int) {
    notificationsTakeAndSkip.tryEmit(take to skip)
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks to your answer, I researched `snapshotFlow` and realized that it is the most suitable for debounce, but I converted the notifications to a regular `MutableState`, because I needed to get not only the most recent result from the server, but also add it to the previous response, and as far as I understood `StateFlow` does not allow you to somehow add new values to the previous ones. Therefore, after that I implemented `debounce` in the simplest way - I canceled the `Job` if the next one appeared and added a `delay` before calling the request

Comment: MutableStateFlow does allow you to do what you're describing. For example `mutableStateFlow.value = mutableStateFlow.value + someNewValue` or `mutableStateFlow.update { it + someNewValue }` But my code above is using SharedFlow instead of StateFlow as an example, because I didn't know if you had a default value.